# How can I filter different window partitions in SQL with different values? I.e. Partition A to be filtered by 3, partition B to be filtered by 5, etc

Tags: sql

I have one loan with two different installment numbers (1 and 2). In the dpd counter, as soon as the value reaches 0, I do not want the rows after that. So in the case of loan_id = 12345, installment number = 1, rank = 5 (as soon as dpd reaches to 0), I want to filter away the row after (loan_id = 12345, installment number = 1, rank = 6, S/N 6).

Same with loan_id = 12345, Installment number = 2, as soon as dpd reaches 0 again (S/N 11), I want to filter away the 3 rows beneath. I have thousands of such records and there is a pattern to it. Rank column is also created by the windows partition formula.

Is there a way I can filter out only specific sets of records that I want for each partitioned window (based on rank value) and discard the ones that I do not want, based off the rank value for each loan_id and installment number combination?

| S/N | loan_id | Installment number | dpd | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 12345 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 12345 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 12345 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 12345 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 6 | 12345 | 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 7 | 12345 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 12345 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 9 | 12345 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 12345 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 12345 | 2 | 0 | 5 |
| 12 | 12345 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 13 | 12345 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 14 | 12345 | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 15 | 12345 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 16 | 12345 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 17 | 12345 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 18 | 12345 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 19 | 12345 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 20 | 12345 | 3 | 3 | 6 |

I have another table where I have the rank that I stop at for each loan id/installment number combination. For reference, it looks like this:

| S/N | loan_id | Installment number | rank to filter until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 12345 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 12345 | 1 | 3 |

I can't seem to join these 2 tables together such that I include only ranks where rank_to_filter_until <= rank.

Thanks! Please let me know if it's not clear. Much appreciated!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  Also, `dpd` is `0` for the first row in both installments.  So your rule suggests that you want only that row.

Comment: With a `CASE` expression?

Comment: yes, then what about dpd =0 for rank 1 ?

Comment: Hey guys, dpd=0 for rank 1 I am not looking to filter for that. Basically for installment number 1, I want dpds with dpd=0,1,2,3,0, for installment number 2, I want dpds with values = 0,1,2,3,0 and for installment 3, I want records for dpd=0,1,0. I want to filter away the other rows. Think I wasn't clear in my earlier explanation @eshirvana

Comment: @Larnu how should I write that case statement....?

Comment: `CASE` **expression**, @Jiaks .

Comment: Yeah.. @Larnu, could you suggest how the logic looks like? Cant seem to see it for this case

Comment: I would suggest looking at the documentation for the RDBMS you are using; I can't link you as you are yet to correct them.

Comment: how do you calculate rank column? do you have a date column ? how the rows are sorted? also which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

this query is depends on the rank column calculated , if you could provide how you calculated rank ,this query could be different , but here is how you can do it :

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT * , MAX(CASE WHEN dpd = 0 THEN RANK END) OVER (PARTITION BY loan_id, installment) mr
FROM yourtable
) t
WHERE t.rank <= mr 
ORDER BY loan_id , installment;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes this worked. It was part of a way larger table to derive the rank calculations but thank you for it!